# Material-UI show letter avatar when ther is no image

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, avatar

I am using Material-UI Avatar React component  for show  profile images.I need to show letter avatar when there is no image from given url. How can I achieve this?.

```
<Avatar src={ProfileImageUrl} className={classes.avatar}>
   {userDetails.fistname.charAt(0)+" "+userDetails.lastname.charAt(0)}
</Avatar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Avatar component itself has an alternative attribute like the standard `img` tag

```
   <Avatar alt="avatar" src={ProfileImageUrl} className={classes.avatar}>
       {userDetails.fistname.charAt(0)+" "+userDetails.lastname.charAt(0)}
    </Avatar>
```

Comment: alt  attribute working fine for my task , but  how can I change look and feel like letter avatar ? Is there an any way to style  like letter avatar

Comment: so you should do a conditional render, I have never worked with Material-UI but from API I understood either you should have Avatar component with `src` and `alt` or no `src` to render letter version

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alt` attribute directly, [Ref](https://material-ui.com/demos/avatars/)

```
<Avatar alt="No Image" src={ProfileImageUrl} className={classes.avatar}>
       {userDetails.fistname.charAt(0)+" "+userDetails.lastname.charAt(0)}
</Avatar>
```

Or, you can use a condition to show default `letter`, [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
,considering you are having `userDetails object`

```
<Avatar Image" src={ProfileImageUrl} className={classes.avatar}>
     {Object.getOwnPropertyNames(userDetails).length>0 ? userDetails.fistname.charAt(0)+" "+userDetails.lastname.charAt(0) : 'No Image'}
</Avatar>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I just solved this issue in my project:-**

If there's an error in the url mentioned in `src`, the `Avatar` component would fallback to the children i.e, the text you've provided:- `{userDetails.fistname.charAt(0)+" "+userDetails.lastname.charAt(0)}`.

This would result into a letter avatar.

[Link to the documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/avatars/#fallbacks)